# Python: dynamically composed regex not working in finditer

Tags: python, regex

I want to find matching words in a sentence, with the word being dynamically supplied. I wrote the following code which works with the example:

```
text="Algorithmic detection of misinformation and disinformation Gricean perspectives"
found=re.finditer(r"\bdetection\b", text)
for i in found:
    print("found") #this line prints exactly once
```

But since I need the target word as input that is not known a-priori, I changed the code like below, and it stopped working:

```
text="Algorithmic detection of misinformation and disinformation Gricean perspectives"
word="detection" #or passed by other functions etc.
found=re.finditer(r"\b"+word+"\b", text)
for i in found:
    print("found") #this line does not print in this piece of code
```

How should I correct my code please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
found=re.finditer(r"\b"+word+r"\b", text)
#         raw string here ___^
```

Comment: does `word` also need to be raw string?

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 1):

Simply with [Raw f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#raw-f-strings):

```
text = "Algorithmic detection of misinformation and disinformation Gricean perspectives"
word = "detection"  # or passed by other functions etc.
pat = re.compile(fr"\b{word}\b")   # precompiled pattern
found = pat.finditer(text)
for i in found:
    print("found")
```